# C# インスタンスについて

Tags: c#

C#にて、インスタンスについてご教授をお願いいたします。。
ソースファイルは、program.cs と Class1.cs の二つあります。
program.csがメインとなります。
以下に例えのプログラムを示します。

将来的に、プログラムは常時起動し、何か信号を受信したら、出力し、出力したらリセットはせず、待機状態にします。また、信号が来たら・・・の繰り返しです。
出力の期待値は最終的に a=4 です。
どの信号にも a=4 となるようにしたいです。

考えでは、信号がくるたびにclass1をnewし、Global.Cntが初期化された状態で使用されると思っています。
しかし、初期化のされている様子は見当たらなく、ご質問いたしました。
初歩的なことでのご質問お許しください。

順々に信号がくるのを模擬したプログラムです。

program.cs↓↓

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)　　//2回の信号が順々にきた
        {
            int a = 1;

            Class1 class1 = new Class1();
            a = class1.A(a);
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Class1.cs↓↓

```
class Class1
{
    public static class GlobalV
    {
        public static int Cnt = 0;
    }

    public int A(int a)
    {
        int ans = 0;

        GlobalV.Cnt++;
        ans = B(a);

        return ans;
    }

    public int B(int b)
    {
        int c = 2;

        b = GlobalV.Cnt + c + b;
        return b;
    }
}
```

続けてで申し訳ないのですが、もし、A信号の処理をしている最中に、
B信号が来た場合、新たにclass1がインスタンスされた場合、A信号で処理していたclass1は併合もしくは消えてしまうのでしょうか。
同時に来た時は・・・

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

長文、分かりにくい質問で申し訳ありませんが、ご教授下さると幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GlobalVは内部クラスですがstaticクラスのためインスタンス間で値が共有されています。下記コードと等価です。

```
class Class1
{
    public static int Cnt = 0;
}
```

インスタンス生成時に初期化する予定ならCntはフィールドで保持すべきです。

ただし、「常時起動し、何か信号を受信したら、出力し、出力したらリセットはせず、待機状態」という条件を考えると、受信機インスタンスはプログラム中1つだけでいいように思います。

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Receiver receiver = new Receiver();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)　　//2回の信号が順々にきた
    {
        int a = 1;

        a = receiver.A(a);
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

次に信号の連続受信についてですが、今回の実装では受信機インスタンスのスコープはループ内のみとなっています。そのため、ループの外から受信機インスタンスにアクセスすることはできず、
近いうちにガベージコレクションで消える運命なので、「消えてしまう」といって差し支えありません。B信号で処理していたclass1も同様です。

余談ですが、今回の実装だとA信号の処理が終了するまでB信号の送信が行われません。そのため、同時に信号が来るということはありません。この辺りをどうするかは仕様によりますが、考えられるパターンはこんな感じですね。

1. 送信は一気に行い、処理は順次行う：受信機にキューを実装して順次処理を行わせる。
2. 送信は一気に行い、処理は受信ごとに行う：マルチスレッドで送信・処理を行う。

以上、お役に立てれば幸いです。

Comment: *Cntはフィールドで保持すべきです*は現状でも`static`フィールドですのでインスタンスフィールドとすべきでは。

Comment: その通りですね。言葉足らずでした。

Comment: rhizaria様、pgrho様、お礼が遅くなり申し訳ございません。rhizaria様の方法で解決できました。有難うございました。